# Using Kafka Streams TopologyTestDriver - how to test left join between two streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to test a stream-stream join with `TopologyTestDriver`. My goal is to confirm, without running external services, that my topology performs the following left join correctly.

```
bills
  .leftJoin(payments)(
    {
      case (billValue, null) => billValue
      case (billValue, paymentValue) => (billValue.toInt - paymentValue.toInt).toString
    },
    JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMillis(100))
  )
  .to("debt")
```

In other words, if we see a `bill` and a `payment` within 100ms, the payment should be subtracted from the bill. If we do not see a payment, the debt is simply the bill.

Here is the test code.

```
val simpleLeftJoinTopology = new SimpleLeftJoinTopology
val driver = new TopologyTestDriver(simpleLeftJoinTopology.topology)
val serde = Serdes.stringSerde

val bills = driver.createInputTopic("bills", serde.serializer, serde.serializer)
val payments = driver.createInputTopic("payments", serde.serializer, serde.serializer)
val debt = driver.createOutputTopic("debt", serde.deserializer, serde.deserializer)

bills.pipeInput("fred", "100")
bills.pipeInput("george", "20")
payments.pipeInput("fred", "95")

// When in doubt, sleep twice
driver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofMillis(500))
Thread.sleep(500)

val keyValues = debt.readKeyValuesToList()
keyValues should contain theSameElementsAs Seq(
  // This record is present
  new KeyValue[String, String]("fred", "5"),
  // This record is missing
  new KeyValue[String, String]("george", "20")
)
```

Full code available at https://github.com/Oduig/kstreams-left-join-example

Is it possible to test a left join this way?

Comment: What is the actual result you are getting when running the test case?

Comment: The output in `keyValues` is `Seq(KeyValue("fred", "5"))`

Comment: I tried replicating the behaviour (using Java) and I am getting the same results as yours. One key observation to note i.e. when I used `JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(100)));` which I know is deprecated method instead of `JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMillis(100))` I am getting the correct results ie. 3 records in the debt topic

Comment: @deadzg_devil Interesting. This happens due to the so-called `enableSpuriousResultFix` which is enabled in the newer methods but disabled in the old ones. To quote a discussion board:

"We should change the implementation of the join, to not emit eager left/outer join result, but instead delay the emission of such result after the window grace period passed."

With the old methods, what we see is an immediate output of the left records, followed by an output of the merged record. As I see it, the correct answer for this left join would be 2 values: a merge (fred) and a timeout (george).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Kafka Streams works with "stream time", which is based on the event time of a record. The event time can come from multiple sources.

1. Explicitly set in the Record itself by the producer.
2. At runtime, if the event time is not set, Kafka uses the wall clock time of the broker.
3. At test time, if the event time is not set, the `TestInputTopic` takes a fixed timestamp, which can be optionally incremented after every record by passing `autoAdvance`.

My code was working at runtime, because Kafka used wall clock time by default but the test topics do not. This means that the so-called "stream time" was frozen in my test, and the window for `"george"` was never closed.

We can set the time explicitly (or use `autoAdvance`) to trigger the correct behavior.

```
val t0: Instant = Instant.now()
bills.pipeInput(new TestRecord("fred", "100", t0))
bills.pipeInput(new TestRecord("george", "20", t0))
payments.pipeInput(new TestRecord("fred", "95", t0))

// Sending an extra record with a later event time
payments.pipeInput(new TestRecord("percy", "0", t0.plusMillis(101)))

val keyValues = debt.readKeyValuesToList()
keyValues should contain theSameElementsAs Seq(
  new KeyValue[String, String]("fred", "5"),
  new KeyValue[String, String]("george", "20")
)
```

The test now passes. Note that there is no way to advance stream time, without sending a new record to the topic. This means if the data is very sparse, it can take a long time (on the wall clock) for records to be emitted.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out the key for me was adding the explicit time to each input record. It doesn't seem to work if you only add time to the last record.